# Problems when passing the text box input to another page - specifically first name and lastname in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JavaScript coding with html and the things that's bugging me right now is passing a variable to another page in java script.
So my codes for the first page are:

```html
<html>
<head><title>lol1</title></head>
<body>
<form action="lol2.html">
<input  type="text" name ="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
<input  type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
<input  type="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and second page are:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
lol2
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
    var queries = queryString.split();
    document.write(queries); 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

After I enter the value in the text box it takes me to the second page but the result is shown like this:

[image]

so how do i get rid of the "firstname=" and "Secondname="? or find an effective way to solve problem.

Comment: This seems kind of related to this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @KiranShahior@WillFrautschy as i mentioned above i am new to coding and i don't really  understand queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem really doesn't have anything to do with textboxes or forms or passing data from one page to another. It's simply a matter of how you are attempting to extract the querystring.

You must pass a string to the **[`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method for it to actually perform the split:

```js
var queryString = "firstName=Scott&lastName=Marcus";
var queries = queryString.split("&");  // <-- You weren't passing a string to split on
// Get each name/value pair:
console.log(queries[0]); 
console.log(queries[1]); 

// Get just the values:
console.log(queries[0].split("=")[1]); 
console.log(queries[1].split("=")[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has a built in method for this: [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and [`searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

You can use it like:

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let firstname = params.get("firstname");
let lastname = params.get("lastname");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLSearchParams, specifically the `URLSearchParams.values()` method to get just the values. Just keep in mind [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) if you are going to use this on the web.